StringTake :Cannot take positions 1 through 1 in
Here is the code that aims to figure out first letter of each sentence in a string of text:
StringTake[StringTrim[StringSplit[WikipediaData["computers"],"."]],1] 


It will help to know what it means by the error in red displayed:
StringTake
:Cannottakepositions1through1in.

StringTake
:Cannottakepositions1through1in.

StringTake
:Cannottakepositions1through1in.


Your text contains "..." in "semiconductor material ... wherein all the components of the 
electronic". This creates empty strings and "StringTake" complains about it.

The included image shows that there may not be a character to extract so the StringTake command issues warning.
Try:
StringTake[StringTrim[StringSplit[WikipediaData["computers"], "."]], 
 UpTo[1]]


TextSentences is a simpler and better method than StringSplit when you want to locate sentences in text.
text = WikipediaData["computers"]; (* 12 November 2024 revision *)
sentences = TextSentences[text];

These sentences solve problems like these examples where "etc." and "e.g." and the name "Derek J. de Solla Price" are not split.
sentences[[{17,39}]]


Peripheral devices include input devices (keyboards, mice, joysticks, etc.), output devices (monitors, printers, etc.), and input/output devices that perform both functions (e.g. touchscreens).


The Antikythera mechanism is believed to be the earliest known mechanical analog computer, according to Derek J. de Solla Price.

Update to fix a problem caused by lowercase characters in a formula in the text
Combine TextSentences with StringCases to remove characters that are not letters and we get 411 uppercase letters and 4 lowercase letters from a formula in the text:
Flatten@StringCases[
    StringTake[TextSentences[WikipediaData["computers"]], 1],
  LetterCharacter]

(* {"A","M","T","T","A","C"  [...]  "P","E","A","T","M"} *)

Here's a way to remove the lowercase letters:
Flatten@StringCases[
    StringTake[TextSentences[WikipediaData["computers"]], 1],
  RegularExpression["[A-Z]"]]

Explanation for StringCases
Look at the output from StringTake. There are characters like "=" which are caused by section headings in the Wikipedia article, e.g. "== Etymology ==", and other characters from a formula in the text.
StringTake[TextSentences[text], 1]

StringCases removes these characters that do not start sentences in the text.

As TextSentences will be taking care of locating the beginning of each sentence and allocating one element for each sentence, not clear why StringCases still needed. I understand how StringSplit fails to discern beginning of each sentence given usage of say etc. will lead to anything after period in etc. as a new sentence.

StringCases removes characters that don't start new sentences. For example, a problem is caused by section headings in the Wikipedia article, and by a formula that TextSentences doesn't recognize. See my update for more details.

It is still not clear on what basis, Wolfram Mathematica rightly decides that in this sample text, "Resrly" is not the first word of a new sentence.  https://www.canva.com/design/DAGWzN0emvg/2DcgI5MJU2mTzJ7ucKjoaA/edit?utm_content=DAGWzN0emvg&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton
